# Model->insert($data) not inserting data into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-4

I'm using CodeIgniter v4.4.1. I'm trying to insert Customers into my MySQL database. My Customer table has only two columns for now (for testing): `idcustomer` (primary key, not null, auto increment), and `name` (varchar(45)). That's working fine.

My `Customer` model looks like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idcustomer';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $allowedFields = ['name'];
}
```

In my controller,

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
// use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\Customer;

class CustomerController extends BaseController
{
//...
    public function store()
    {
        $customerData = $this->request->getPost();

        // return view('customer/test', $customerData);
        // I used this line above to test if I had any data in $customerData, and I was able to access the data from the post request there. So up to here, everything is working fine.

        $customer = model('Customer');
    
        $customer->insert([
            'name' => $customerData['name'],
        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/customers');
    }
//...
}
```

When I submit a form, the post request is submitted successfully, and I am even redirected to the `/customers` route (as indicated in the controller's `store()` method. However, when I check my database, the new customer is not inserted. The database remains the same as it was before... I would have expected the new record to be created in the customer table.

I removed all validation to test, and it still is not working. I am not getting any errors, exceptions, or anything in the writable/logs.

So, I tried doing this in my controller:

```
public function store()
    {
        $customerData = $this->request->getPost();
        $customer = model('Customer');
    
        $customer->insert([
            'idcustomer' => 22, // that is, an ID number that does not exist yet in my database (the highest existing ID is 5)
            'name' => $customerData['name'],
        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/customers');
    }
```

When I submit the form again, now a new entry *is* created, but, it is created with the `idcustomer` = 6.

Now, when I do:

```
$customer->save([
            'idcustomer' => 3, // an existing ID
            'name' => $customerData['name'],
        ]);
```

Then, the entry with `idcustomer = 3` is modified (as expected).

I also tried the `$customer->save(...)` method, and it's not working either.

So, bottom line, my question is, **why is a new record not inserted into the database when I do not pass in the primary key, `idcustomer`?**

Comment: This is by design, please read on [save(), a wrapper around the insert() and update() methods](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#model-save)

Comment: @Vickel, I read the documentation, and, as I understand it, it should still create a new entry when I don't pass in the primary key. I also tried using the `insert()` method, but I'm still not getting a new row inserted into my database... Any idea what's wrong? (I updated my question to reflect this).

Comment: id=22 --> nothing to **update**, fall back to **insert** using next primary key (in your example --> 6)

Answer (score 0):

> `$useAutoIncrement`:
> Specifies if the table uses an auto-increment feature for $primaryKey. If set to false then you are responsible for providing primary key value for every record in the table. This feature may be handy when we want to implement 1:1 relation or use UUIDs for our model. The default value is true.

You have to set this in your model-file (if this represents your db-schema) or you have to explicitly provide the primary key for every query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Simon; however, I tried it, and it's still not working. Your answer says, "The default value is true", so setting it to true in the Model has no different effect... Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change it like this:

```
    public function store()
{
    $customerData = $this->request->getPost();
    $customer = new Customer(); // Instantiate the Customer model

    $customer->insert([
        'name' => $customerData['name'],
    ]);

    return redirect()->to('/customers');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried doing that too; it's still not working. :(

Comment: This does only create a new model-class instead of a shared model-instance.